# Where is the DLR Expression Tree API?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime, linq-expressions

Linq Expression Trees can be found in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace in the System.Core.dll assembly.

In which assembly and in what namespace is the DLR Expression Tree API?

Is it that the DLR adds more language elements as more expression classes to the same assembly and in the same namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 and later, they are one and the same (the DLR uses `System.Linq.Expressions`).  There are just more expression types than in earlier releases (exception handling, control flow, dynamic binding, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I was misled by this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28299/Generate-AST-for-the-DLR) but I then looked that it was written in 2008. Even the DLR documentation relating to expression trees available on the codeplex website (http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=dlr&DownloadId=246540) does not explicitly state that they use the same namespace and assembly. A bit of poking in with Reflector, however, confirmed what you're saying. Thank you.

Comment: Just to add more detail to you answer, here's a useful link I found for anyone else who might need an answer to this question: http://dlr.codeplex.com/discussions/282550

Comment: The DLR can actually be deployed against earlier .NET versions, and in those cases the new and improved `System.Linq.Expressions` APIs will be included in the various `Microsoft.Scripting` assemblies (and, I think, in different namespaces to avoid collisions with .NET 3.x LINQ).

Comment: Thanks, Mike. That's what I read in the article I linked in the previous post. Until 2011, the DLR AST API was in the `Microsoft.Scripting.dll` and `Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll` assemblies. And the namespace was `Microsoft.Scripting.Ast`. The discussion thread I linked to in the previous post is from DLR website on CodePlex and it even has a conditional compilation construct to check the .NET framework version and insert the appropriate using statement, just as you describe.